# Trouble looping through array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to loop through the array, and if all the elements are equal or less than zero  it will display the winner screen. At the moment, it displays the winner screen when the play button is clicked.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray().Length; i++)
{
    if (parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()[i].getMonHealth() <= 0)
    {
        Winner winners = new Winner();
        winners.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the health? are any of them 0 or less

Comment: We aren't that good in psychic debugging, and since a lot of relevant code is missing you'll have to do the debugging yourself. Place a breakpoint and step through your code. Inspect the variables, see why certain values are not what you expect them to be.

Comment: also, please use foreach for this, it's much easier and more readable, since for this occasion you don't need to use a regular for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a bit cleaner with LINQ:

```
if(parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray().All(m => m.getMonHealth() <= 0))
{
    Winner winners = new Winner();
    winners.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

`All()` will check if the condition (`m => m.getMonHealth() <= 0`) is satisfied for all objects in the array.

However, you should make sure that all objects below `parent` are actually initialized. That code will fail, if any of the lists (e.g. `getmonsterarray`()) return null.

Comment: Ok this works thank you, but the issue is now it displays the winner screen six  times, because of the 6 array elements.

Comment: Do you still have the for-loop around it? You don't need that, the expression in my answer already covers all 6 elements.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues here:

- You're calling `parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()` on every iteration of the loop, which is *at least* a bit inefficient, and also makes the code harder to read.
- You should consider using a `foreach` loop unless you really need the value of `i`
- Your current array loop uses `<=` where it should use `<` - an array of length 5 has elements 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4, for example.
- You're showing the "winner" screen inside the loop for *any* player, not if *all* elements are less than 0.
- All these `get` methods are unconventionally named (e.g. `getplayer` should be `GetPlayer`), and some should probably be properties or indexers anyway
- This level of indirection violates the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) very significantly. While I'm not dogmatic about this generally, I suspect you could make this a *lot* cleaner with a bit of work.

Solving just the array part, you could use:

```
bool anyHealthyMonsters = false;
// I've assumed the type of Monster here. You could use var, but you should understand
// what that means thoroughly first.
foreach (Monster monster in parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn())
                                         .getmonsterarray())
{
    if (monster.getMonHealth() > 0)
    {
        anyHealthyMonsters = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!anyHealthyMonsters)
{
    Winner winners = new Winner();
    winners.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

A cleaner solution would be to use LINQ though:

```
if (parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()
        .All(monster => monster.getMonHealth() <= 0)
{
    Winner winners = new Winner();
    winners.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

However, if you're relatively new to C#, I would suggest concentrating on improving the design before you worry *too* much about this. I'd expect the *final* result to look something like:

```
if (parent.CurrentGame.CurrentPlayer.HasDefeatedAllMonsters())
{
    ...
}
```

where `HasDefeatedAllMonsters()` would be a method in your `Player` class, which would be something like:

```
return monsters.All(monster => monster.Health <= 0);
```

(Even the `parent.CurrentGame.CurrentPlayer` part makes me somewhat nervous, but it's hard to mentally redesign a whole app without more context. I strongly suspect that you shouldn't need to ask your "parent" (whatever that is) for the game - this class should know about it directly.)

Comment: Why not use `var` for the type of `monster` in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @MikeofSST: I'm going for clarity for a probable-newcomer. I would probably use `var` myself, but for someone new to C# it's worth understanding the type of the variable first, and then moving on to use `var` when they're more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will display the winners screen if any one of the win conditions is met, not all of them.  Try to compile the conditions into a single boolean value during the loop and then check that at the end (a logial AND operation).

```
Boolean gameIsWon = true;
foreach(var monster in parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray())
{
    gameIsWon &= monster.getMonHealth() <= 0;
}
if(gameIsWon)
{
    Winner winners = new Winner();
    winners.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional boolean var:

```
bool showWinnerScreeen = true;
```

Then check if **all** MonHealth are <0

```
for (int i = 0; i <= parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray().Length; i++)
{
    if (parent.mygame.getplayer(parent.mygame.getpturn()).getmonsterarray()[i].getMonHealth() > 0)
    {
       showWinnerScreen = false;
    }
}
```

finnaly show your screen

```
if(showWinnerScreen)
{
    Winner winners = new Winner();
        winners.Show();
        this.Hide();
}
```

You may use LINQ and .Any() to do the same shorter, more advanced...